# What is the fastest and safest way to move an SVN repository from one host to another?

Tags: linux, svn, scp

I have two SVN repositories about 1.5 GB each that I need to move from one CentOS 5.4 Linux machine to another. They are up into the three to four thousand revision range.

I could simply `scp -r` them over. I did try starting that process and it was clear that it was going to take several hours, maybe all night, so I stopped it to reconsider.

I could use `svnadmin dump` with or without the `--deltas` option, then compress and scp the dump file.

Is there some better approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yep rsync.

Specificly:

```
rsync -hxDPavilyzH source/ user@remote:/target/ --stats
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll look into it and look up all those options. But why would it be better to use rsync over scp? (Note that I only have to do this once.) Is it less likely to corrupt the data than scp?

Comment: these are my 'general purpose' options _(you'd be able to drop -D, could replace -a by -r, compression (-z) is optional depending on bandwith/CPU load)_; scp is unlikely to corrupt the data. But when the connection is dropped, you're back to squre one with scp. Rsync is a good restartable, incremenal backup solution

Comment: rsync is definetly the good solution. An alternate way could be [svn export](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svn.c.export.html) followed by scp.

Answer (score 2):

[`svnsync`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.4/svn.ref.svnsync.html) is designed for this, and should be safe provided nothing else writes to the target repo until the copy is complete.

Hower, `rsync` should also be safe, and allow interruption (svnsync may as well, not sure).